# Recursion of subsequences is not clear

Tags: haskell

The following is the code for subsequences

```
subsequences  [] = [[]]                                                 ---Line1
subsequences (e:es) =  subsequences es ++ map (e:) (subsequences es)    ---Line2
```

I do not understand the recursion in this i.e. how do I get the following output by this code.

```
subsequences [1]
[[],[1]]
```

According to this, first part of Line2 `subsequences es` is reaching `[]` then going to  Line 1 and returning `[[]]`, 
the second part of Line2 `map (e:) (subsequences es)` which is `map (1:) [[]]`which gives `[[1]]`. Now, this clubs with `[[]] ++ [[1]]` and gives the output as `[[],[1]]`.

```
subsequences [1,2,3]
[[],[3],[2],[2,3],[1],[1,3],[1,2],[1,2,3]]
```

According to this, first part of Line2 `subsequences es` is reaching `[2,3]`, 
the second part of Line2 `map (e:) (subsequences es)` will be `map (1:) [2,3]`.
Here is where I am getting confused that how is it reaching to the end of subsequences i.e. the empty list, Am I supposed to look at it in as two different parts? I am not able to figure out how is this called recursively.

Comment: Well, have you tried running it "by hand" on small inputs? What do you think `subsequences [1]` does, and why? Does `ghci` agree? What about `subsequences [2,1]`? (In general: show us you've put some effort in, so we can talk to you about the specific part that's giving you trouble.)

Comment: I have made the changes.

Comment: Not answering your question, but there is a really cute way one-liner way of writing this: `subsequences = filterM $ const [False, True]`.

Answer (score 5):

In your explanation of how you think `subsequences [1,2,3]` should run, you write:

> the second part of line 2 `map (e:) (subsequences es)` will be `map (1:) [2,3]`

This is close, but not quite right! You've dropped the call to `subsequences`, so it should actually be

```
map (1:) (subsequences [2,3])
```

This gives `subsequences` a chance to recurse and produce:

```
subsequences [2,3] = [[],[3],[2],[2,3]]
```

Substituting that into the `map` expression from before, we have

```
map (1:) [[], [3], [2], [2,3]]
=
[[1],[1,3],[1,2],[1,2,3]]
```

which are indeed the final elements of `subsequences [1,2,3]`.